Cronjobs are not getting killed via OOM killer
I am using cgroupsv1 for resource limiting (CPU/RAM) per user using the systemctl command on a CentOS system. A user has configured some cron jobs, and when these cron jobs are executed, they use user.slice for resource limitation. Once a process hits the resource limit, the OOM killer tries to kill it, but it fails with:
kernel: Out of memory and no killable processes

After debugging, I found that cron jobs have oom_score_adj set to -1000 which protects them from the OOM killer.
Is there any way to change the value (from the cgroup side) or any other way to make sure OOM kills the cron jobs whenever they hits the resource limit?
systemctl version :- 219

Could you check whether systemctl show crond | grep -i oom contains any suspicious settings?

Yes , it did show this setting (OOMScoreAdjust=0)

that is good and expected, it means that systemd doesn't set your crond's oom adjust manually

but that means something else is setting these.

It is not systemd that is setting the OOM value, it must be something else, like the cron implementation you are using.

thanks for checking , finally  I found the issue this value for crond service  was getting set by a script
